# How are you supposed to take sharp turns?

Tags: f-zero-99

I can't seem to figure out how I'm supposed to take sharp turns. I always seem to end up at a dead stop and then make the turn, or im gonna slam the wall on exit.

So how are you supposed to take sharp turns? Let go of gas? Slide? Brake? another way?